# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: ????????: Unable to initialize module

Tags: php, installation

After upgrading php from 5.1 to 5.2.10, I got the following warnings when `php -v`:

```
    # php -v
    PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: fileinfo: Unable to initialize module
    Module compiled with module API=20050922, debug=0, thread-safety=0
    PHP    compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=0
    These options need to match
     in Unknown on line 0
    PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: mcrypt: Unable to initialize module
    Module compiled with module API=20050922, debug=0, thread-safety=0
    PHP    compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=0
    These options need to match
     in Unknown on line 0
    PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: memcache: Unable to initialize module
    Module compiled with module API=20050922, debug=0, thread-safety=0
    PHP    compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=0
    These options need to match
     in Unknown on line 0
    PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: mhash: Unable to initialize module
    Module compiled with module API=20050922, debug=0, thread-safety=0
    PHP    compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=0
    These options need to match
     in Unknown on line 0
    PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: mssql: Unable to initialize module
    Module compiled with module API=20050922, debug=0, thread-safety=0
    PHP    compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=0
    These options need to match
     in Unknown on line 0
    PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: readline: Unable to initialize module
    Module compiled with module API=20050922, debug=0, thread-safety=0
    PHP    compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=0
    These options need to match
     in Unknown on line 0
    PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: tidy: Unable to initialize module
    Module compiled with module API=20050922, debug=0, thread-safety=0
    PHP    compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=0
    These options need to match
     in Unknown on line 0
    PHP 5.2.10 (cli) (built: Nov 13 2009 11:24:03)
    Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
    Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2009 Zend Technologies
```

How can I fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 23):

Looks like you haven't upgraded PHP modules, they are not compatible.

Check `extension_dir` directive in your php.ini. It should point to folder with 5.2 modules.

Create and open a phpinfo file and search for `extension_dir` to find the path.

Since you did upgrade, there is a chance that you are using old php.ini that is pointing to 5.1 modules

Comment: `extension_dir` points to `/user/lib/php/modules` in which there are many `.so` files. how can I tell the version of those `.so` files? thx

Comment: When you run php as you did in question, for each incompatible module you will receive warning message:

Unable to initialize module Module compiled with module API=20050922

In your case incompatible modules are: fileinfo, mcrypt, memcache, mhash, mssql, readline and tidy, so try to disable them and see does it make a difference.

Comment: @Horace: If you're on a Unix-like host, try this in the extension dir: `strings -f *.so|grep API`. There may be multiple 'API' strings in each .so, but should only be on with the API version number

Comment: @Marc, that won't work, at least it didn't on OSX when I tried :)

Comment: @bas: hmm. no strings command? grep didn't work? Maybe OSX PHP doesn't include the API version inside the .so file. Could be in the file's metadata (resource fork, extended attributes, whatever it's called these days).

Comment: I tried strings & grep on binaries provided by MAMP/OSX and CentOS/Linux and haven't managed to find API version, now I'm curious where is it or how is it encoded :)

Comment: @Marc B, `strings -f *.so | grep API` returns nothing meaningful, only some "API version" text but no number.

Comment: Heads up for anyone with the same issue.  Check that you aren't using a custom php.ini, that is where you need to change where extension_dir points.

Comment: @Steve I dont have any additional php-config folders and I never touched my php.ini so how would I know what to change?

Comment: @Nameishi you should check out your PHP configuration by running a script with <?php phpinfo(); ?> in it.  If you can't figure it out from there, get in touch with your host tech support

Comment: @Steve Yeah it just started working, i installed Homebrew and restarted my laptop and everything is fine...no idea

Answer (score 14):

try to upgrade each of those modules using pecl command

```
# pecl upgrade fileinfo
# pecl upgrade memcache
# pecl upgrade mhash
# pecl upgrade readline
```

etc...

Comment: by localhost wamp, how can i upgrade in windows?

Answer (score 10):

`brew reinstall php56-mcrypt --build-from-source`

Do this—pass the `--build-from-source` flag—for each module which needs to be compiled with the same version.

It may also require PHP options depending on your plugins. If so, `brew reinstall php56 --with-thread-safety`

To see all of the options for php[version] run `brew options php56` (replacing 56 with your version)

Answer (score 2):

Erase the module that can't be initialized and reinstall it.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old thread, but I stumbled across it when trying to solve a similar problem.

For me, I got this particular error relating to the `php_wincache.dll`.  I was in the process of updating PHP from 5.5.38 to 5.6.31 on a Windows server.  For some reason, not all of the DLL files updated with the newest versions.  Most did, but some didn't.

So, if you get an error similar to this, **make sure all the extensions are in place and updated**.

Answer (score 0):

This is just describing why I had this issue in case someone finds it helpful.

My problem was that I had upgraded php with homebrew and had forced at some point the variable PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR in my profile or bashrc file so it was pointing to the old php version. Removed that line and fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I tried to install a newer version of `PHP`. After finding that I also would need to reconfigure Apache for that I switched back to the old PHP version. Here the solution which worked for me:

change the httpd.conf to the correct versions:

```
 PHPIniDir ...
 LoadModule php5_module ...
```

Changed the

```
PATH - Environment Variable
```

When that does not take any effect

```
rename or delete the new PHP(-Version)-Folder
```

*For some reason the last step did the trick for me. Even after a restart it did not have an effect before doing this.*

Answer (score 0):

If you installed php with homebrew, then check if your apache2.conf file is using homebrew version of php5.so file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, with Windows Server 2008, I had to change the `PATH` variable.
The former version of PHP (VC9) was inside it.

I have changed it with the newer version of PHP (VC11).

After a restart of Apache, it was okay.