# Centos 6.7 x86_64: Can you help me figure out this error?

Tags: linux, xslt, centos6

I get this error in my error_log:

*[02-Sep-2015 00:22:14 UTC] PHP Warning: PHP Startup: xsl: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP compiled with module API=20100525
These options need to match
in Unknown on line 0

[02-Sep-2015 00:22:17 UTC] PHP Warning: PHP Startup: xsl: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP compiled with module API=20100525
These options need to match in Unknown on line 0*

I tried 'pecl upgrade' but there are no packages. I used EasyApache to add xsl, but apparently, PHP upgraded up did not have all the modules updated. I am lost :(

Can someone help?

Comment: Check your /etc/php.d for old .ini files after an upgrade perhaps? Are you compiling your own apache, or are you using the Centos-supplied one with yum install?

Comment: I'm using the EasyApache through WHM. I am not sure how the old .ini files would look like. I can check!

Answer (score 0):

You are using an outdated PHP module and/or are trying to use a module compiled against a newer PHP version. If you [google for your error](https://www.google.com/search?q=PHP%20Warning:%20PHP%20Startup:%20xsl:%20Unable%20to%20initialize%20module%20Module%20compiled%20with%20module%20API%3D20090626%20PHP%20compiled%20with%20module%20API%3D20100525) you find a handful of hits that show you how you could resolve the error:

- [make sure the php location is in your path](https://github.com/liip/php-osx/issues/38) (bottom of thread)
- helps with [debugging / tracking this error using phpinfo](https://forum.directadmin.com/showthread.php?t=48219)
- [hints that you upgraded php, but not the modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130910/php-warning-php-startup-unable-to-initialize-module) (in your case it looks like it is the other way around)