# wampee [Portable wampserver] Setup - Unable to upgrade version of php to 5.5.12 (or higher)

Tags: php, windows, apache, wampserver

I have a setup that I am trying to resolve whereby I moved my installed web app over to a portable app to be able to make it easier to setup for the end user.

No matter what I try I can not seem to get the wampee (Portable wampserver) to be able to recognize and run with an updated php version.

I am getting a series of errors after trying to change the version.  Wampserver is green on my taskbar but I get warnings.

[image]

How do I update the php version of the wampee to a newer version?

My present setup for wawmpee:

Apache 2.2.17

PHP 5.5.12

MySQL 5.5.8

Comment: See answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130910/php-warning-php-startup-unable-to-initialize-module

Comment: But it seems that, in your case, one of the PHP extensions is of newer version than PHP itself.

Comment: The way I tried doing this was to grab the php dir from a wampserver (non portable) and copy it into my wampee (portable version).  I have been stuck on either wampee staying red in the taskbar or going green but with a bunch of warnings.

Comment: I think you will find that PHP5.5.12 does not run with Apache 2.2, it only runs with Apache 2.4. Not there is only a `php5apache2_4.dll` in the PHP directory and not a `php5apache2_2.dll` therefore it only has an interface to Apache 2.4

Comment: I was finally able to upgrade the apache to 2.4.9 and succeeded in the server configuration for the portable wamp.  My configuration is working under apache 2.5.9 and php 5.5.12.  I really thought this was not going to work and almost gave up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is how I achieved the solution to allow for wampee to use php5.5.12 and apache2.4.9**

**First Update PHP**

1)  Grab a copy of PHP 5.5.12 from the existing installation of wampserver 2.5 downloaded from sourceforge.

2) Place php5.5.12 folder from wampserver installation under the wampee folder within bin/php

3)  Under tpl folder (located under wampee root directory) make the following modifications to wampmanager.conf

```
[php]
phpVersion = "5.5.12"
phpLastKnown = 5.5.12
phpIniDir = .
phpConfFile = php.ini
phpExeDir = .


[phpCli]
phpExeFile = php.exe
phpCliFile = php-win.exe
```

4) Under wampee folder under tpl/php/php5.5.12 make the following modifications

```
; XDEBUG Extension

zend_extension = "@PATH_PHP@/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.2.5-5.5-vc11.dll"
```

5) Grab php_xdebug-2.2.5-5.5-vc11.dll from wampserver2.5 and place it under wampee directory under bin/php/php5.5.12/zend_ext

**Second Update Apache**

1) Add Apache2.4.9 from wampserver2.5 and place it under wampee folder under bin/apache

2) Create folder Apache2.4.9 under tpl/apache under wampee main directory

3) Copy php.ini from tpl/php/php5.5.12 into the tpl/apache/Apache2.4.9 folder under bin directory

4) copy httpd.conf from tpl/apach2.2.17/conf into tpl/Apache2.4.9/conf and ensure  php5_module is as follows within httpd.conf

```
LoadModule php5_module "@PATH_PHP@/php5apache2_4.dll"
```

**Next update wampmanager.conf under tpl/wampmanager.conf**

```
[apache]
apacheVersion = "2.4.9"
apacheLastKnown = 2.4.9
apacheExeDir = bin
apacheConfDir = conf
apacheExeFile = wampeehttpd.exe
apacheConfFile = httpd.conf
apacheServiceInstallParams = -n wampapache -k install
apacheServiceRemoveParams = -n wampapache -k uninstall
```

> Important: Don't forget to copy httpd.exe from bin/apache/Apache2.4.9
>   as a copied file named wampeehttpd.exe (wampee relies on this file)

**Finally update wampee.ini to the new php and apache versions**

1) Navigate wampee/resources and ensure that the following values are present, and if not startup wampee to make it populated (updated) from the tpl (tempalate) files.

```
[wampserver]
apache_version=2.4.9
php_version=5.5.12
mysql_version=5.5.8
phpmyadmin_version=3.3.9
sqlbuddy_version=1.3.2
webgrind_version=1.0
[ports]
apache=80
mysql=3306
```

**That should do it, and now you will have an updated wampee (portable wampserver) that runs with a newer php and apache version.**