# How to install SSH2 for PHP5.6

Tags: php, ssh, libssh2

I need to install SSH2 to my PHP5.6. So as I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15134421/php-install-ssh2-on-windows-machine) accepted answer I downloaded zip [from here](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/ssh2/0.12/) then coppied php_ssh2.dll and php_ssh2.pdb to php/ext and libssh2.dll to Windows/system32. And after Apache restart and SSH2 call it throws me this error:
 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: ssh2: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20121212
PHP    compiled with module API=20131226
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: ssh2: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20121212
PHP    compiled with module API=20131226
These options need to match

How can I solve it? Thanks you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130910/php-warning-php-startup-unable-to-initialize-module

Comment: It looks like SSH2 extension is older than my PHP instalation. Also as I see latest release of SSH2 for PHP for PHP5.5.